# C++ - Cross platform menu bar and context menu using SFML

Tags: c++, cross-platform, sfml

Does SFML provide any cross-platform way to create a menu bar and context menus? Or am I just going to have to do it myself using the Windows API/XOrg?

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: example image]

Comment: SFML doesn't hahve any ready-to-use widgets or such at all. You pretty much have to build everything yourself. There are a few GUI libraries that can take some of the heavy lifting off your hands, or do it yourself

Comment: @super, just to make sure we're talking about the same thing, in the example image I'm only talking about the dialogs which are boxed in red, not anything in the background. Sorry if that's already what you meant.

Comment: SFML does not have that. Try [dear imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) to render a GUI in combination with SFML.

Comment: Alright I'll check that out, thanks.